# Confusion related to L1 and L2 svm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, svm

I have this confusion related to L1 and L2 svm. It is given in this [paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/cddual.pdf) that

The dual problem is given by

$$
min(\alpha) = 1/2*\alpha^T\hat Q\alpha - e^T\alpha
$$
subject to

$$
0 <= \alpha_i <= U
$$

$$
\hat Q = Q+D
$$
D is a diagonal matrix  and $Q_{ij}=y_iy_jx_i^Tx_j$. For L1 SVM U=C and $D_{ii}=0$. For L2 SVM U=inf and $D_{ii}=1/2C$

I didn't get what this U term is and why is in the case of L2 SVM U=inf and $D_{ii}=1/2C$. How was it derived?

This is how I tried to derive it but I think I am making certain mistake

$L(w,b,\zeta,\alpha,\gamma) = \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 + C\sum_i\zeta^2 - \sum_{i}\alpha_i(y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i) } +b)-1+\zeta_i) - \sum_{i}\gamma_i\zeta_i
$

Differentiating with respect to $w,\zeta$ and b

$w=\sum_i\alpha^{(i)}y^{(i)}x^{(i)}$

$\sum_i\alpha_iy^{(i)} = 0$

$2C\zeta_i = \alpha_i + \gamma_i$

Now when I substitute these values into the objective function I get

$-\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 + \sum_i\alpha_i-C\sum_i\zeta^2)$

I don't get the expression as given in the paper. I know I am pretty close but I think I am screwing up somewhere. Can anyone give some suggestion where I am wrong?

Comment: You should write out the dual mechanically by using the Lagrangian (Boyd's book on convex optimization explains this step by step process quite well).

Comment: Is svm "singular value method"? $\:$

Comment: @SureshVenkat I tried to derive it myself. However, I think I am making certain mistake. I have edited the post showing what I have tried. Can you provide some suggestions where I am wrong? I know if I manipulate some of the terms I will get it.

Comment: @RickyDemer in this context SVM = support vector machine

Comment: You forgot to substitute for $\|w\|^2$. that will recover the quadratic term in $\alpha$

Comment: @SureshVenkat. I substituted the $||w||^2$ to get the quadractic term in $\alpha$. But how do I get the D in $\hat Q = Q+D$. I can't get it from $C\sum_i\zeta^2$ term

Comment: @SureshVenkat. Any suggestions. It's already more than a week, I am stuck in it

Comment: The question is simultaneously cross-posted. 